# Variable scope in Apigee Edge. Request and Response

Tags: oauth-2.0, scope, apigee

I am working with Apigee edge lately and am having trouble with a specific implementation. Essentially, the client will request an oauth token from their API through apigee. However, to make calls to our proxy they need an oauth token from us as well. So far my flow goes like this.

Client calls token endpoint on apigees side, a service callout is made to get a token from one of our other proxies (returned as a JSON object). Then the request passes through and gets the token from the clients API.

Here is where I am having trouble. After the response from the clients API, I want to use the assign message policy to modify the response to include the first token that was grabbed from our other proxy. The problem is the variable seems to be falling out of scope between request/response.

Am I missing something obvious here? I have looked into the `PopulateCache` policy, but I feel like this may be overkill as I only want the variable to remain in scope for the request/response.  Sorry if my explanation is not very good, I am VERY new to Apigee Edge.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't missing anything obvious. Variables should not fall out of scope between request and response flows. You are right that PopulateCache isn't necessary.

One item that catches people sometimes is how you access the response from the service callout. If you configure the service callout response to be stored in a variable called calloutResponse, then when you access the body to extract information, you'd use calloutResponse.content as the source. If you try to access calloutResponse instead, you might think that the variable had disappeared.

Add more details/trace if that is not the problem, and we can figure out what is going wrong.